# failed to execute script Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to update the some values in a particular field, which I want to be unique.

But when I give the script the condition .unique() it returns me an  error.

If I do not give the condition unique then it's keep updating again and again.
Means the value will be

update_field= array ('world','values','frost','world','values','frost',...)

What I am doing wrong here anyone knows !!!

```
        $script['script'] = 'ctx._source.update_field = (ctx._source.update_field + new_value).unique()';
        // unique() is giving the error but why
```

error message ---

> {"error":"ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to execute
>   script]; nested:
>   GroovyScriptExecutionException[MissingMethodException[No signature of
>   method: java.lang.String.unique() is applicable for argument types: ()
>   values: []\nPossible solutions: minus(java.lang.Object),
>   minus(java.util.regex.Pattern), minus(java.lang.Object), size(),
>   size(), use([Ljava.lang.Object;)]]; ","status":400}

a sample documents ---

```
    hits: {
        total: 19,
        max_score: 5.5197725,
        hits: [
            {
                _index: "myIndex",
                _type: "myType",
                _id: "pdd9da099f380b3951a627a5d5a38758680016f16",
                _score: 5.5197725,
                _source: {
                    content: "After shooting attacks are several police cars sent to the streets to watch. 
                    title: "The police in Copenhagen when bødemål despite extra tasks",
                    update_field: "[funny]"

            }},}
```

So there you can see that the update_field is not empty and have some value -
when when i try ---

```
$script['script'] = 'ctx._source.update_field = ((ctx._source.update_field ?: []) - new_value).unique()';
```

it also returns me the same error ! 
don't know why !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error, the key point is `No signature of method: java.lang.String.unique()`. It's probably because `update_field` does not exist or is empty at some point and thus the `+` operator will simply try to concatenate it as a string with the array you're specifying.

One way to fix this would be to make sure `update_field` is considered as an array no matter what. You should be able to achieve this by replacing `ctx._source.update_field` with `(ctx._source.update_field ?: [])`, that way if `update_field` does not exist or is empty, then an empty array will be used instead and the `+` operator will work on an array instead of on a string field.

```
$script['script'] = 'ctx._source.update_field = ((ctx._source.update_field ?: []) + new_value).unique()';
```

Comment: thanks for your answer and explanation, but it is also return me the same error, i have also update my question with a sample document, can you kindly have a look, thanks a lot

Comment: You probably need to wipe your `myIndex` index and recreate it, because your `update_field` has already been indexed as a string, i.e. `"[funny]"`.

Comment: @oops my bad, thanks a lot Val, thanks a lot for your help :), you are awesome

Comment: i have reindex my documents and it is working perfectly, thanks a lot for your help again :)